# Recursos de cadenas en Ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic

Hola tengo una duda sobre cómo manejar los recursos de cadena y valores en ionic o en otro framework. Me explico:

En android, todos los recursos de cadenas, dimensiones... están contenidos en un fichero XML en la carpeta res/values. Tal y como funciona en android puedo usar el mismo recurso en diferentes partes de mi aplicación y así evitar escribirlo repetidas veces o incluso tener diferentes idiomas etc...

Mi pregunta es si existe algo parecido en ionic.
He pensado en tener un fichero de recursos de cadena con constantes, pero no se si es es del todo correcto.

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres. ¿Ficheros de i18n (internacionalización)?

Comment: Se guardan en **src/assets**, pero para los textos debes interpolar con algún pipe